# Transforming string wrapped with double asterisks on both sides to a bold text

Tags: macros, bold, text

I am trying to convert `**sometext**` to bold. I came across the following snippet:

```
\makeatletter
\def\starparse{\@ifnextchar*{\bfstarx}{\itstar}}
\def\bfstarx#1{\@ifnextchar*{\bfitstar\@gobble}{\bfstar}}
\makeatother
\def\itstar#1*{\textit{#1}\starON}
\def\bfstar#1**{\textbf{#1}\starON}
\def\bfitstar#1***{\textbf{\textit{#1}}\starON}
\def\starON{\catcode`\*=\active}
\def\starOFF{\catcode`\*=12}
\starON
\def*{\starOFF \starparse}
\starOFF
```

that could help me transorm a text wrapped with `**` on both sides into bold text. But it also transforms `*sometext*` into italics. I only want to detect double asterisks and transform it into bold.

I tried removing :

```
\def\itstar#1*{\textit{#1}\starON}
```

but it gives a `undefined controlled sequence error`. How could I do this?

Comment: I thought there are some packages help you use Markdown inside LaTeX?

Comment: @JouleV Yes, there is. Could we do this without using the `markdown` package?

Comment: @Amanda Yes, the code implements markdown syntax, like in this site: `*italic*`,  `**bold**`, and `***bold-italic***`. What should be the output of `***bold-italic***`? **`*bold-italic*`**, ***`bold-italic`***, or `***bold-italic***`?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik It must go undetected. Only text surrounded with `**` must be considered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed the code a bit so that:

```latex
\starON
*italic*

**bold**

***bold-talic***
\starOFF
```

prints:

> [image]

The code does no verification whatsoever to guarantee that the input is not something like `**bold***`. When the code finds a `*` it checks if there is exactly one `*` more (ignoring spaces), and if there is it grabs everything until the next `**` (no spaces allowed between `*`s), so `* *bold**` is valid, but `**bold* *` is not.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\starparse{\@ifnextchar*{\bfstarx}{\starignore}}
\def\bfstarx#1{\@ifnextchar*{*\starignore}{\bfstar}}
\def\starignore{*\starON}
\makeatother
\def\bfstar#1**{\textbf{#1}\starON}
\def\starON{\catcode`\*=\active}
\def\starOFF{\catcode`\*=12}
\starON
\def*{\starOFF\starparse}
\starOFF

\begin{document}

\starON
*italic*

**bold**

***bold-talic***
\starOFF

\end{document}
```